# OpenCV fisheye::projectpoints assertion faild

Tags: opencv

I want to project a single point (-1450,-1660) on an image 
I am using opencv 4.0.1 c++ 
I have the camera matrix and distortion coefficient
and my code is

```
    vector <Point3f> inputpoints;
    Point3f myPoint;
    myPoint.x = -1450;
    myPoint.y = -1660;
    myPoint.z = 0;
    inputpoints.push_back(myPoint);

    vector<Point2f> outputpoints;

    vector<Point3f> tvec;
    tvec.push_back(Point3f(0, 0, 0));

    vector<Point3f> rvec;
    rvec.push_back(Point3f(0, 0, 0));

    double mydata[9] = { 3.3202343554882879e+02, 1., 6.4337059696010670e+02, 0, 3.3196938477610536e+02, 5.3844814394773562e+02, 0., 0., 1. };

    Mat mycameraMatrix = Mat(3, 3, CV_64F, mydata);

    double mydata2[4] = { -1.1129472191078109e-03, 4.9443845791693870e-02,
        -7.2244333582166609e-03, -1.7309984187889034e-03 };

    Mat mydiscoff = Mat{ 4,1, CV_64F ,mydata2 };
    Mat newCamMat1= Mat(3, 3, CV_64F);

   cv::fisheye::projectPoints(inputpoints, rvec, tvec, mycameraMatrix, mydiscoff, outputpoints);
```

when I run the program I get this exception

```
OpenCV(4.0.1) Error: Assertion failed (mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN(type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)) in cv::debug_build_guard::_OutputArray::create, file c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix_wrap.cpp, line 1395
```

I changed the type of camera matrix and distortion coefficient to CV_32f but I still got the same error , I am a very beginner in openCV ..so can any one tell me what caused this exception? 
I know the rvec should be 3*3 but I just followed someone else code who wrote that can be written in this way

Comment: I edited the rotation matrix using cv::Rodrigues but still have a problem

Answer (score 1):

okay the problem was that projectpoints and fisheye::projectpoints differ in the order of parameters ..so I was putting the order which belongs to projectpoints